# Determine if sending from specific mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like add an acronym of my name at the end of the mail subject if sending it from a specific mailbox.

Example:

I have two mailboxes in Outlook, mail1@mail.com and mail2@mail.com.

When sending mail from mail1@mail.com the code should check if the acronym is present in the subject, if not add it.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim xText As String

    'text I would like to add at the end of mail subject
    xText = "/MX"

    If oAccount = "mail1@mail.com" Then 'part which does not work
        If InStr(Item.Subject, xText) = False Then
            Item.Subject = Item.Subject & " " & xText
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your variable `oAccount` ? You did not declared it or set it.

Comment: That is right apologize. I have declared `oAccount` as `Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account`

Comment: This is declaration, You need to also `Set` it.

Comment: Something like `If oAccount = "mail1@mail.com" Then … ElseIf oAccount = "mail2@mail.com" Then … End If` seems adequate.  Is there some reason why this would not work?  As Teamothy says, you must set oAccount to the sender email address..

Comment: Replace oAccount with Item.SendUsingAccount

Answer (score 0):

You should get the result required with `.SendUsingAccount` rather than Account.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim xText As String

If Item.Class = olmail Then

    'text I would like to add at the end of mail subject
    xText = "/MX"

    Debug.Print Item.SendUsingAccount

    If Item.SendUsingAccount = "mail1@mail.com" Then

        If InStr(Item.Subject, xText) = False Then

            Debug.Print Item.Subject
            'If item cannot be edited post another question

        End If

End If

' for testing, cancel ALL sending
' remove to allow sending
Cancel = True

End Sub
```